# Reading pdf file from firebase

Tags: android, firebase

Can anyone tell me how can i read a pdf file directly into my android app without downloading it from firebase?
I have uploaded a pdf file in firebase storage and now i want to read that file in my app without downloading it.

Comment: Show the code you've tried so far and where you're having an issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple
Use a web view in your layout and load the firebase pdf file url into your webview.